# compile error when trying to use polymorphism C++

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have a base class **Model** which declared and implemented in **Model.h** which has include guard as well:

```
#ifndef Model_h
#define Model_h
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include "Node.h"
#include <map>
using namespace std;
class Node;
class Model
{
public:
    void add(Node*);

protected:
    map<int, Node> nodes;

};

void Model::add(Node *n)
{
    nodes.insert(make_pair(n->returnTag(),*n));
}

#endif
```

and I want a child class **Node** - which declared and implemented in **Node.h** with include guard as well - to inherit **Model** class like this:

```
#ifndef Node_h
#define Node_h
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include "Model.h"
class Node;
map<int, map<int, Node>> tnodeMap;
map<int, Node>::iterator nodeIter;
class Node:public Model
{
public:
    Node();
    int returnTag();
   /*some code*/
};
/*implementation*/
#endif
```

but when I try to build it i got **error C2027 undefined type 'Node'**
if I omit `class Node;` statement in **Model.h** I get syntax error about identifier of **Node**

I'm confused what is the problem?

Comment: `map<int, Node> nodes;` this statement needs concrete Node type.

Comment: You have a circular include problem.  Can you explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: well I need access to `nodes` map declared as protected value in `Model` class, in `Node` class that's why I want `Node` class to inherit `Model` class.

Comment: Well, what you have now won't work, and it isn't clear how polymorphism enters into this since it generally requires a pointer or reference but you're not storing either.  If you mean to have other classes inherit from Node you'll end up with slicing problems.  That's why I asked you to describe what you're trying to do since whatever it is it seems you're going down the wrong road right now.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not related to polymorphism, but to circular dependency.
You can't have a container of Nodes (such as your `map<int, Node> nodes`) declared in `Model`, because this creates a dependency to `Node` for `Model`. However, `Node` is dependent from `Model`(since `Node` inherits from `Model`).

Hence the problem.

There are however a couple of other problems.

1. Why does your add method in `Model` require a Node pointer and then proceeds to a copy (by înserting *n in your map)? Who owns that pointer? What is its lifetime?
2. Why is there another `Node` map globally defined in the `Node` class?
3. Why is your implementation of the `Node` and `Model` classes in their respective header files? Because of the intricated dependency between `Model` and `Node`you won't be able to have the implementation of Model dereference a Node object if you mix it with the header. When you're not working with templates you should separate the declaration and the implementation.
4. What is the relationship between `Model` and `Node`? Can you say that a `Node`*is* a `Model`? This hierarchy looks strange to me.

Anyway, here is a fixed example that should work (untested though).

**Model.h**

```
#ifndef Model_h
#define Model_h
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <conio.h>
// We SHOULD NOT include Node.h in this file
class Node; // Forward declaration is enough
using namespace std;
class Model
{
public:
    void add(Node*);
protected:
    map<int, Node*> m_nodes;
};
#endif // Model_h
```

**Model.cpp**

```
#include "Model.h"
// In the implementation file we CAN NOW include Node.
#include "Node.h"
void Model::add(Node* n)
{
    m_nodes.insert(make_pair(n->returnTag(), n));
}
```

**Node.h**

```
#ifndef Node_h
#define Node_h
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include "Model.h"
// NO NEEED to forward declare the Node class
map<int, map<int, Node>> tnodeMap; // Why is this global?
map<int, Node>::iterator nodeIter; // Why is this global?

class Node: public Model
{
public:
    Node();
    int returnTag();
   /*some method declarations*/
};
/* implementation IN IMPLEMENTATION FILE */
#endif // Node_h
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer I will consider changing my code structure surely but still I get same error `use of undefined type 'Node'` :(

Comment: Did you try the example I wrote in my answer? I had to remove the global definitions of `tnodeMap` and `nodeIter`, but otherwise it did work for me (it fails at link time because I didn't bother to define a `main`, but there is no `undefined type` error. Of course you **have to** separate the declarations and the implementation for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Your both header files are interdependent on each other. Make one header file independent.

If the compiler tries to compile the first **node.h**, it will find `include model.h` in this file.
So it will jump to **model.h** to compile it. Here, it finds the **model.h** file but because of `ifndef`, it skips this line and there. Here it still doesn't know about class node existence. So when you omit the class node line,  you would get this error.

Comment: try removing #include "Node.h" line in model.h file and keep class Node  as it is in model.h